# what does fn.apply(fn, []) do?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code which accepts `fn` as the argument and stores it in an `object` property.

```
var obj = {};

function anotherFn(fn){
   obj["name"] = fn.apply(fn, []);
}

function google(){
    console.log("hello");
}
anotherFn(google);
console.log(obj.name);
```

What i am not understanding is the `fn.apply(fn,[])` code and its purpose. Normally we use `call` and `apply` method when we want to execute a `fn` in a different `this/context`.

But what does the `fn.apply(fn, [])` do here?. The confusion is why can't i just do

```
obj["name"] = fn();
```

Comment: That call **does** execute `fn` in a different `this` context, that being the function object itself.

Comment: I would recommend never doing something like this in production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fn.apply(fn, [])` calls the function stored in `fn` with a context (the value of `this` while executing the function) of `fn`, and the arguments contained within `[]` (no arguments).

It seems odd to call `apply` in that way, when it would have been equivalent to call `fn.call(fn)`.

`fn()` would *not* be an appropriate replacement, as `fn()` will execute in the global context, which means that the value of `this` within the function will be `window` (assuming a browser environment).

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me why the output on console for `obj.name` is "undefined", either with `fn.apply(fn, [])` or with `fn()`?

Comment: @Verhaeren, please use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button on the top right to ask new questions.

Comment: It's because there isn't anything being returned in the `fn()` invocation. You need to return some sort of value for a variable definition to take place. for example, if you change the `google()` function to `return 4;` instead of `console.log();`, `obj.name` will equal 4.

Comment: @zzzzBov: fn.apply(fn, []); , this would be useful when i am calling the function from a different context altogether. console.log(obj.name) executes the function in obj context right and not global?

Comment: @Shane, `console.log(obj.name)` doesn't execute a function. It simply logs the value that `fn.apply(fn, [])` had previously returned.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a contrieved sample showing how it can be different:

```
var obj = {};

function anotherFn(fn){
   obj["name"] = fn.apply(fn, []);
}

function anotherFn2(fn){
   obj["name"] = fn(fn, [])
}

function google() {
    console.log(this.world);
}
google.world = "yay!"

anotherFn(google);
anotherFn2(google);
```

The output is:

```
yay!
undefined
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c56ja3jL/

Depending on the context, this might be useful. The basic idea is that you always have `this` equal to the function itself, instead of the global context.